# Proving $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x) = 0$ where $t$ is Thomae's function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm trying to prove $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x)  = 0$ where $t(x)$ is Thomae's function.

I believe I have a proof, but the hint in the book I'm using is suggesting a different approach which I don't understand. I have two questions: 1) Is my proof also correct? 2) How do I do the proof the way the book is suggesting?

---

My proof goes as follows:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then pick $N := \lfloor 1/\epsilon \rfloor + 1$ and set $\delta := \frac{1}{N}$. (Note that $\delta < \epsilon$.) Now let $x \in \Bbb R$ ($x \not= 1$) satisfy
$$ | x - 1 | < \delta = \frac{1}{N}.$$
If $x$ is irrational, then $t(x) = 0$, so $|t(x)| < \epsilon$.

If $x$ is rational, then there exist $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ (and $q > 0$) such that $x = p/q$ is fully simplified. So 
$$ \frac{N-1}{N} < \frac{p}{q} < \frac{N+1}{N}$$
which implies $q > N$ since $x \not= 1$. So $|t(x)| = \frac{1}{q} < \frac{1}{N} = \delta < \epsilon$.

---

However the hint in the book says I should do the following:

> Given $\epsilon > 0$, consider the set of points $\{ x \in \Bbb R: t(x) \geq \epsilon \} $. Argue that all the points in this set are isolated.

All such points $x$ must be rational (so of the form $p/q$) such that the denominator $q$ is small enough: $\frac{1}{\epsilon} \geq q$. Since $D := \lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rfloor$ is the maximal allowed denominator, every $x$ is isolated since $(x-\frac{1}{D}, x + \frac{1}{D})$ cannot contain any other points from the set.

But how do I use this to prove $\lim_{x \to 1} t(x) = 0$?

Comment: Your argument is correct. The hint in the book will require essentially the same argument as yours. If that is done, then by $t(1)=1$, and the set of points $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:t(x)\geq\epsilon\}$ is isolated, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(1-\delta, 1+\delta) \backslash \{1\}$ does not contain any points from $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:t(x)\geq\epsilon\}$. This means $t(x)<\epsilon$ for all $x$ in $(1-\delta, 1+\delta) \backslash \{1\}$.